# In Python, is it possible to access the global namespace from within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python coming from a good background with other languages. My question is mostly academic, as I know that what I'm asking is seldom needed and is definitely not a good programming practice.

Here is what I'm asking:

```
x = 'global scope'      # global
def func():
    x = 'local scope'   # global x is now shadowed
    print(global x)     # is this somehow possible?
```

**Attempt #1**

```
def attempt1():
    x = 'local scope'   # shadowded
    global x
    print(x)            # error
```

This results in an error: name 'x' is assigned to before global declaration.

**Attempt #2**

```
def attempt2():
    x = 'local scope'   # shadowded
    print(__main__.x)   # error: __main__ not defined
```

The Python documentation on namespaces states suggest that #2 (or something like it) should be possible. See [Python Tutorial 9.2](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html)

> "The statements executed by the top-level invocation of the interpreter, either read from a script file or interactively, are considered part of a module called __main__, so they have their own global namespace."

However attempting to access `__main__` from either a script or the console results in an error. Also, the global attribute `__name__` refers to the outermost module as `__builtins__`, but this only contains the built-in variables, not any user defined global ones.  If the variable were delcared in an outside module, one that had been imported, it could be accessed with `__module_name__.variable`.

Comment: If you want to access a global variable, I suggest not hiding it with a local variable of the same name.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can get a global variable, or specifically whether you can access a global variable *with the same name* as a local variable?

Comment: What about globals() (returns a dict out of all global variables)? globals()["x"]

Comment: In order to use `__main__`, you need to `import __main__`.

Comment: What's your actual objective here? It seems unlikely that you're going about it the right way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try globals():

```
x = 'global scope'      # global
def func():
    x = 'local scope'   # global x is now shadowed
    print(globals()['x'])     # is this somehow possible?


func()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `globals()['x']`.  However, you're better off just giving your local variable a different name so you can just do `global x` to do whatever you need to do with the global variable.

Answer (score 5):

`globals()` returns a dictionary of the current global variables.  You can print `globals()['x']`.

Answer (score -1):

If python3, you can try the following method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def list_available_subclasses_names(obj):
    """Check the type if has __globals__ attributes.
    """
    return [
        subobj.__name__
        for subobj in obj.__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()
        # 'wrapper_descriptor' object has no attribute '__globals__'

        if hasattr(subobj.__init__, '__globals__')
    ]


def get_builtin_function(obj, subclass_name, func_name):
    """Get function obj.
    """
    func = None
    for subobj in obj.__class__.__base__.__subclasses__():
        if subclass_name == subobj.__name__:
            __globals__ = subobj.__init__.__globals__       # gloabls is here.
            __builtins__ = __globals__.get('__builtins__')
            func = __builtins__.get(func_name)
            break

    return func


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = ''
    subclass_name = 'Repr'  # print(list_available_subclasses_names())

    func_eval = get_builtin_function(obj, subclass_name, 'eval')
    if func_eval:
        func_eval('__import__("os").system("pwd")')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do, or what it accomplishes that the use of `globals()` in other answers does not.