# Python how to call function from the global namespace when something in your local namespace have the same name?

Tags: python, namespaces

In Python how do you call a function from the global namespace if something in your local namespace have the same name? for example in C++ you'd do `::globalNamespaceFunc();` and in PHP you'd do `\GlobalNamespaceFunc();`

```
def lol():
    print("outer lol")

def f():
    def lol():
        print("inner lol")
    lol(); # runs inner lol
    # how to call outer lol?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, is it possible to access the global namespace from within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163569/in-python-is-it-possible-to-access-the-global-namespace-from-within-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `globals()["lol"]()` . Also there is no need for `;` after calling lol `lol()`

Answer (score 0):

idk if this is a *good* solution, but using globals() seems to work:

```
def lol():
    print("outer lol")

def f():
    def lol():
        print("inner lol")
    lol(); # runs inner lol
    # how to call outer lol?
    globals()["lol"]()

f()
```

prints

```
inner lol
outer lol
```